# CSS padding-left value of <code> is applied for only the first line

Tags: html, css

When I apply a padding-left style definition for a code tag as like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  code {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<code>git pull origin master<br />
git push origin master
</code>
</body>
</html>
```

The result was like below. That is, the padding-left style was applied for the first line only.

Is this behavior as HTML5/CSS specification? To apply the padding for all lines, should NOT I use the padding-left?

[image]

Comment: <code></code> <br /> <code></code>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<code>` is an  `inline element`, so you need to change it into `display:block/inline-block` to achive that

```css
code {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<code>git pull origin master<br />
git push origin master
</code>
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that the code element is an inline element. Yes, I was able to confirm that all lines were padded at specifying the display style. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your style.

display: block;

Answer (score 0):

`<code>` is an inline element, so the padding will not apply to your code as expected since the `<br>` element in your code simply breaks the line as opposed to truly starting a new one.

One way to fix this is to apply `display: block;` to the `<code>` element, but it looks like the ideal solution for you will be to use the `<pre>` element instead since you want to do a multi-line code block.

```
<pre>
  git pull origin master
  git push origin master
</pre>
```

Let me know if you have any other questions. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, actually, I wanted to use the combination of both pre and code tags. Thank you for your answer!